# angular 2 selected text option

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 how can I get the selected text from an option. Also since I have a dynamic number of selecs? (I think I need to add to an array) t how Can I get the text for all. I was able to get the value but what I need is the text.

HTML

```
 <div class="row  left" *ngFor='let control of tabControls'>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-left" style="border:1px dotted">
                        {{control.DropDownTitle}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                        <select [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
                            <option *ngFor='let controlList of control.DropdownValues' [ngValue]="controlList.Value">
                                {{controlList.Value}}
                            </option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
```

component

```
 onChange(selected: any) {
        console.log('selected item ' + selected);
    }
```

Note:tabControls is an interface

in the console it print

```
selected item 1: 2017
```

however, the other selections(month, company) lose the selection
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2:** I just noticed that you're iterating through the tabs via `*ngFor` so there are actually 3 select elements so you need 3 different ngModel bindings.

So first, change the type of your `selected` property inside your component to an `array` of any and **initialize** it.

```
selected: any[] = [];
```

Then, declare an index, i, on your *ngFor and bind ngModel to `selected[i]`:

```
<div class="row  left" *ngFor='let control of tabControls; let i = index'>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-left" style="border:1px dotted">
                    {{control.DropDownTitle}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
                    <select [(ngModel)]="selected[i]" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
                        <option *ngFor='let controlList of control.DropdownValues' [ngValue]="controlList.Value">
                            {{controlList.Value}}
                        </option>
                    </select>

                </div>
```

Comment: :) I have a question: what properties do each item in the control.DropdownValues array have? I notice that what you're displaying inside the option element is controlList.Value but what's bound to [value] is just controlList. Could you try this: [value] = "controlList.Value"

Comment: Another thing you could do is declare a getter and setter for selected.
Like this (with a private backing field)
     
`private _selected: any;

get selected(){
   return _selected;
}

set selected(value: any){
    this._selected = value;
   console.log('selected item: ' + this._selected);
}`

And get rid of the `onChange` event in select:
`<select [(ngModel)]="selected">`

Comment: If I do this [value]="controlList.Value" it works, however, All the other dropdowns lose the selection. So looking at the image above if i select the year I do get 2017 but Month and Company list  lose their selection

Comment: ok, going back to the way you originally had it with the change event:    
`<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">`        inside your onChange method, what does this print out:    `console.log('selected item ' + selected.Value);`     basically printing out `selected` prints the object. You can do: `JSON.stringify(selected)`  to print the object in JSON format or if it's just the value you're interested in, print out `selected.Value`

Comment: updated my above code, other dropdowns lose the selection

Comment: Apologies for not realizing that select is inside the *ngFor div so there are actually three select elements which all bind to the same model. I updated my answer above. Could you give it a shot?

Comment: THANK you Very much, it worked. I just would like to understand how selected becomes the text value of the select? in the component we only have selected: any[] = []; which is not assigned to the text value?

Comment: Awesome! So the "box of bananas" syntax, `[(ngModel)]` means you're creating a two-way binding. Which means you can update your model (selected[i] in your component) through your view (the DOM element that is option) and vice versa. When your page first loads, none of the combos will have anything selected. But once the user interacts with one the combos, it causes a binding update from view to model. You can also change the selected value from your component as long as it's set to a value that exists in the dropdown. Like: `selected[1] = '2017'` or `selected[1] = tabControls[1].someProperty`

Comment: Here is some more details here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `ngValue`, which binds the whole object, but with that, add `ngModel` in the mix, but that means you have another variable. Maybe there is a better way to solve this, without an extra variable. If so, please do tell!

So change your code to something like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" (ngModelChange)="onChange(selected)">
     <option *ngFor='let controlList of control.DropdownValues' [ngValue]="controlList">
          {{controlList.Value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

And in your component:

```
selected: any;

onChange(selected: any) {
  console.log('selected item ' + selected);
}
```

The error you are getting is because you need to import `FormsModule` to your `NgModule`.

Here's a working **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jhTMRTIoguCBjmDkLAmD?p=preview)**

Comment: where do you put ngValue? i did this                                     <option *ngFor='let controlList of control.DropdownValues' [ngValue]="controlList">
 and got a parse error

Comment: @rgoal updated my answer. This works, but it's a bit of a workaround...

Comment: Ah, okay so you have SEVERAL dropdown lists, not only one. Well, that was essential information, of course this solution won't work then... :D

Comment: Please provide a plunker with static data, this was more complicated than thought, and would be easier to solve by having a plunker to play with! :)

Comment: Thank AJT , the issue was resolved by  muzurBurcu 11 . However, you answer can help me for another case (one drop only). therefore will select your answer is helpful

Comment: You are welcome, the most important thing is that your problem is solved! :) Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over you list, from which you are binding your drop down.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select" [(ngModel)]="selectedStdId">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let std of lstStudents" [value]="std.id">
        {{ std.name }} 
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Here, `lstStudents` is your array with `id`, `name` which populates the drop down.
You will get the selected value like
`this.selectedId = this.selectedStdId;`
Now you all have to do is that loop through your `lstStudents` array and get the `name` from it whose `id` corresponds to the `this.selectedStdId`. Eg,

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.lstStudents.length; i++) {
    if(this.lstStudents[i].id == this.selectedStdId) {
        this.yourDesiredText = this.lstStudents[i].name;
    }
}
```